# Rotate image/context before saving to file

Tags: ios, rotation, uiimage, transform, cgcontext

How do I rotate my context?

I've tried all combinations with `CGAffineTransformRotate()` and `CGContextRotateCTM()` I could think of and can't make it work.

The code below works good. It is capturing various-size images with their background so that they're always 320x480 or 480x320. That's important. However, I want horizontal images to rotate 90 degrees just before saving to file.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(480, 320), NO, 0.0);
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];           
    UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[allImagePaths objectAtIndex:currImg]];
    iv.image = im;
    iv.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;               
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();       
    [iv.layer renderInContext:context];
        //
        // how to rotate it around here?
        //
    UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 1.0);
    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    [imageData writeToFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"result.jpg"] atomically:NO]; 
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Whenever I add any kind of rotation it just gets bugged (white result image or only half image on screen and not rotated).

Any help with this example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucks to answer my own question but well...

Seems the main problem was the coordinate system. Rotating with `CGContextRotateCTM()` does it around the (0,0) point by default. Means the image "hides" out of view. I had to do `[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,-320,480,320)];`.

Also I had to use 2 contexts. First one horizontal to capture the horizontal image with background. The 2nd one vertical to save rotated vertical image.

Answer (score 2):

Use this category method for inspiration.  This will not do exactly what you want, but the idea is the same.

```
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation 
{   
    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}
```

Comment: Can't make it work with transform. Maybe just dunno how to use it in my example.

Comment: Thanx hundreth, i just come across this link while searching rotation based on UIImage orientation and it worked for me.. thanx a ton.. you saved my time..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, not tested yet:

```
  CGSize size = imageIsHorizontal ? CGSizeMake(480, 320) : CGSizeMake(320, 480);
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextRotateCTM(context, 90 * M_PI / 180);
  [image drawInRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, size}];
  UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 1.0);
  NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  [imageData writeToFile:[docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"result.jpg"] atomically:NO];
```

Comment: If "image" is my image from file then it doesn't work. White and not rotated result file.